# Encoding error in ajax request to rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am working on an application in which i have a situation to send text data to backend through Ajax call.

But when the text **"%" occurs** in the text to be sent through ajax, i get the below response from my rails app

```
Internal Server Error 
invalid %-encoding
```

i tried adding escape characters infrot of % symbol, but its not useful.

Any suggestion on this issue would be helpful.

---

**Jquery ajax call used :**

[image]

thanks,
Balan

Comment: Can you show the javascript code you are using for the ajax request?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the question with the actual jquery code used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass jquery an object for the data option and it should correctly escape it for you:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/controller",
  data: {
    text: text_from_text_area,
    current_poster: current_poster
  },
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

See the docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/